# Proving that ${\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n}={\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} B_n}$

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

I'm trying to give my interest more into set theory and I found one problem that seems to be interesting for me. Can anyone show me the solution to this problem?

> $$\text{ {$A_i$}} - \text{infinitely many subsets. Let
> }B_n={\bigcup_{i=1}^{n} A_i}. \text{Prove that
> }{\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n}={\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} B_n} $$

Comment: This follows almost immediately from the Axiom of Extensionality.

Answer (score 1):

$$A_n\subset B_n=\bigcup_{i=1}^{n} A_i\implies \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n\subset \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}B_n. $$.

Now conversely, if $x\in \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}B_n $ then there is $n_0$ such that, $$x\in B_{n_0} = \bigcup_{i=1}^{n_0}A_i$$

Hence there is $1\le i_0\le n_0\le n$ such that

$$x\in A_{i_0} \subset \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n$$

Therefore, $$\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n\supset \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}B_n. $$.

Comment: But in ${\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n}={\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} B_n}$ the upper bounds are infinity

Comment: The rough structure of the argument actually does still hold, even though only finite bounds are mentioned in this answer. My answer has addressed this, but it's basically the same proof.

Comment: @Karagum you are right but in fact it does not matter any way put whatever you want there

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $x \in \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i$. Then certainly $x \in A_n$ for some $n$, and it's immediate that $x \in \bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i = B_n$, so that $x \in \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} B_i$, giving $\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i \subseteq \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} B_i$.

Conversely, suppose $x \in \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} B_i$. Then $x \in B_n$ for some $n$, or $x \in \bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i$. Thus, we have $x \in A_k$ for some $k$ between $1$ and $n$ inclusive, whence $x \in \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i$. As a result, $\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} B_i \subseteq \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i$, proving equality.